# Mysql command does not execute with the user provided

Tags: mysql

I want to create a script to dump all my databases into separate files.
I found a similar script online but on my machine it does not execute properly.
The script is:

```
#! /bin/bash
HOST="host" 
USER="user"
PASSWORD="pass" 

databases=`mysql -h$HOST –-user=$USER --password=$PASSWORD -e "SHOW DATABASES;" | grep -Ev "Database"` 
for db in $databases; do
    mysqldump -h$HOST –-user=$USER --password=$PASSWORD --routines \
      –-databases $db | gzip > "$db.gz" 
done
```

When i run the script I get: `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'some_user'@'host' (using password: YES)`.
What am I doing wrong ?

I am connecting to mysql with another user that the one I am logged in the system. Is this a problem? The mysql user used has all the privileges.

If I run the command that selects databases manually everything works fine.
Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL stores its users in an internal database called mysql; they are completely independent from the system users.

The table mysql.user contains boolean columns like Select_priv, Insert_priv, etc which tell the rights the users have. These can be altered by the [grant command](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html).

In short, it is like this (here, ALL PRIVILIGES renders the user to be like root to the given database and table):

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database.table TO 'user'@'host' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

A mysqldump without restrictions needs all privileges. (you restrict to only stored procedures, I think this also needs all privileges.)

When running as shell script, consider quoting and escaping your password (use a password which does not need escaping) on the executing line:

```
mysql ... --password="$PASSWORD" ...
mysqldump ... --password="$PASSWORD" ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. The problem was the grep in the show databases line.